# Extracting a string from a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some text in a cell in google sheets, example -   `February1—SG4601382 (PS xxxxx 12345.666 and 12345.667)`

I'm trying to extract just the `SG4601382` part into another cell, the `S` character starting position varies in each cell as sometime the date may be February1 sometimes February12.

Do any of you good people know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is generic enough to look for the "—", try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"—([A-Z0\d]+)")
```

Or a little less specific:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"—(\S+)")
```

[image]

---

**Edit;** As an array:

```
=INDEX(IF(A1:A="","",(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A,"—(\S+)"))),)
```

Answer (score 3):

The shortest one would be

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"—(\w+)")
```

[image]

Or as an array

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(
     REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"—(\w+)")))
```

*(Do adjust ranges and locale to your needs)*

**EDIT** *(following [JvdV's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66363931/extracting-a-string-from-a-cell/66364983?noredirect=1#comment117327588_66364983))*

As an alternative so as to ***"free all cells below"***, try

```
=QUERY(INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B,"—(\w+)")), 
          "where Col1<>'#N/A' ")
```

Comment: Nice way of doing the array. First time I see that use of `IFERROR()`. I'll remember that.

Comment: @JvdV If you liked the `IFERROR()` way, I think you will love the `QUERY` one. Please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you should be able to use [regexextract](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=nl).

```
=regexextract(A2, "—(.*?)\s")
```

[image]

This can be turned into an arrayformula easily.

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), regexextract(A2:A, "—(.*?)\s"),))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use the **SEARCH** function to find the position of **"S"**

for example if  "February1—SG4601382 (PS xxxxx 12345.666 and 12345.667)" is your text in A1 cell then

```
=SEARCH("S",A1,0)
```

which give you the position of **"S"** as  **11**

now if **SG4601382** is the string with length 10 every time then you can extract it with **MID** formula like below

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("S",A1,0),10)
```

gives **SG4601382**

Comment: if your string starting with S before your required number then this formula fail.. for that, you need to search for another pattern like in this case "SG" instead of "S"